Search driveItem with query of Document-ID
My goal is to read out the driveItemId from the Document-ID.
Document-ID is a unique SharePoint column that is given to every file in the SharePoint library.
I tried using this method below to get a driveItem (by its driveItemId) using search with a query:
public async Task<string> GetDriveItemIdAsync(string driveId, string docId)
{
    try
    {
        var query = $"Dokument-ID:{docId}";

        var results = await _graphClient.Drives[driveId].SearchWithQ(query).GetAsSearchWithQGetResponseAsync();

        if (results.Value.Count == 1)
        {
            _logger.Info($"Found one document with documentId '{docId}' in drive '{driveId}'.");
            return results.Value.FirstOrDefault().Id;
        }
        else if (results.Value.Count == 0)
        {
            _logger.Info($"No document with documentId '{docId}' found in drive '{driveId}'.");
            throw new Exception($"No document with documentId '{docId}' found in drive '{driveId}'.");
        }
        else
        {
            var driveItemId = results.Value.FirstOrDefault().Id;
            var message = "Dokumente: \n";

            foreach (var item in results.Value)
            {
                message += $"Name: {item.Name}, Id: {item.Id}\n";
            }

            _logger.Error($"More than one document with documentId '{docId}' found in drive '{driveId}'. Returning the first item with driveItemId == '{driveItemId}' \n{message}");
            MessageBox.Show($"Mehr als ein Dokument mit der DocumentId '{docId}' in Laufwerk '{driveId}' gefunden. Melden Sie sich sofort bei der IT und zeigen Sie diese Fehlermeldung. \n{message}", "Fehler", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            return driveItemId;
        }
    }
    catch (ServiceException ex)
    {
        _logger.Error($"Error while trying to get last version of item with documentId '{docId}' in drive '{driveId}'. Exception: '{ex}'");
        throw;
    }
}

I haven't quite understood query yet, with certain documentID inputs I get no item back at all, and with others I get much more than just one item back, even though the documentID column doesn't match at all.
It is behaving very strangely, probably because my query is not yet correct.
Thanks for your help, I'm also open for a better solution for getting the driveItemId by DocumentID in a SharePoint library.

Edit:
Using filter could be a solution too, but i think the anwser in this post is no longer valid, couldnt find anything in the documentation about it.

To get the DriveItemID use this query https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/DriveID/root/search(q='DocumentID') and the id returned is the DriveItemID

Did you try the above query? Its for single document to fetch driveitemid. Query

I tried it. var results = await _graphClient.Drives[driveId].SearchWithQ($"{docId}").GetAsSearchWithQGetResponseAsync();
Its almost the same as in my code in the question and it behaves very wierd. It sometimes returns more than just the driveItem i need.

Yes it returns more information, you just need to do modify the code to return id

I know, but it returns a list of driveItems that dont even have that DocumentId. Sometimes around 50 items are returned. Maybe because it is also searching for file content.
This is the request i used:{https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/{driveId}/search(q='{DocumentId}')}

Okay but when I tried in my environment it returned only particular item

Strange, I am working with a template library for Word documents and the templates are very close to each other, sometimes a template is created based on another template in the library. So I only want to search for the DocumentId in the SharePoint column as this is the only field that is unique. I will try the solution from the answer below.

I would use v1.0/search/query endpoint to find listItem by documentId. What I remember, you actually need listItem id. What's important documentId is related to listItem, not a driveItem
using Microsoft.Graph.Search.Query;
using Microsoft.Graph.Models;

var documentId = "7NDKNNDUE4VT-1387038990-1"
var requestBody = new QueryPostRequestBody
{
    Requests = new List<SearchRequest>
    {
        new SearchRequest
        {
            EntityTypes = new List<EntityType?>
            {
                EntityType.ListItem,
            },
            Query = new SearchQuery
            {
                QueryString = $"dlcDocId:{documentId}",
            },
        },
    },
};

var result = await graphClient.Search.Query.PostAsQueryPostResponseAsync(requestBody);

if (result.Value[0].HitsContainers[0].Hits[0].Resource is ListItem listItem)
{
    var siteId = listItem.ParentReference.SiteId;
    var listId = listItem.SharepointIds.ListId;
    var listItemId = listItem.SharepointIds.ListItemId;
}

If you want to limit searching to a specific site and document library:
"queryString": "dlcDocId:7NDKNNDUE4VT-1387038990-1 AND path:\"https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/{site_name}/{library_name}\""


Isn't searching across the whole SharePoint slow when you look at the performance? Is it possible to search only in a Site or Document-Library?

Definitely, you can limit searching to a specific site, I will update the answer

Searching only for DocumentId works fine but when trying to add the path like this, i dont get any results anymore. QueryString = $"dlcDocId:{docId} AND path:'https://{_domain}/sites/{siteName}/{libraryName}'",
Im very sure that the variables _domain, siteName and libraryName are correct.

I have also noticed that the listItemId always appears at the end of the DocumentId, separated by a - character. DocumentId = "{prefix}-{some chars that are identical in this library}-{listItemId}"
Is this intentional on SharePoint's part? This would also allow me to go directly to the listId without having to make an API call.

@EliahThommen path should be in double quotes QueryString = $"dlcDocId:{docId} AND path:"https://{_domain}/sites/{siteName}/{libraryName}""

@EliahThommen Regarding to the last part of DocumentId, I don't have any inside, it looks like the last number is autoincremented, but I'm not sure if it was intended to be the same as listItemId. But you still need a list id, right?

Yes that last number is autoincremented. I just noticed that this number is always exactly the listItemId and could be taken out with string splitting. It's just a noticeable phenomenon, I'm not sure if this is consistent. Thanks again for you help, the double quotes fixed the issue with the path.

@EliahThommen I'm thinking about the case when a document is moved from one library to another one. DocumentId should be still the same, but once the document is moved, the last part of DocumentId won't match with the list item id in a new library.

This is not an use case in my situation.
